# Remove and add a class in a button jquery, can't make it work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button on the page with a class  `next-main-button`.

On page load, a modal is displayed and I have a button with class `look-task-again`. If I click on it I want to remove `next-main-button` class from next button and add  this class `next-task-error`

Here is the next button:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-main-button" id="next-button" >Next</button>
```

This event is executed when the modal button is clicked, here next-main-button is removed  and next-task-error is added.

```
$(".look-task-again").off("click").on("click", function(){
        $('#error-popup-message').modal('hide');
        $("#next-button").removeClass("next-main-button");
        $("#next-button").addClass("next-task-error");
        });
```

If I inspect element the class is changed but if I click in the next button, the event with removed class is executed:

```
$('.next-main-button').off("click").on("click", function(){
        nextButtonClick();
    });
```

Not this:

```
$(".next-task-error").off("click").on("click", function(){
        errorButtonClick();
    });
```

I tried to use unbind method and to bind the button again, I did it like this :

```
  $("#next-button").removeClass("next-main-button").unbind( "click" );
  $("#next-button").addClass("next-task-error").bind( "click" );
```

In this way the next button is deactivated, nothing happens! Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: I suppose you have done a bit of confusion between ids and classes, *e.g.* you refer to `#next-button`, but this button doesn't have any id.

Comment: bind should have a second parameter, a function, to be useful

Comment: @AlessioCantarella I updated my question. I deleted that ID while I was writing the code here. Just  let's make it simple. All I want is to remove and add a class of a button on other button click.

Comment: @Adder is any other method to use instead of bind?

Comment: Instead to bind/unbind handlers on a button, you could just check the available class on your button and run the proper function.

Comment: You pretty much tried all methods. There's also the three argument form of "on('click', '.where', function(){}))" which might be useful. It is used only once.

Comment: That's the point the class is changed and removed and still the method of the removed class is executed on button click.

Comment: @Adder Can you explain it a little bit more please?

Comment: @EgzontinaK could you please publish your entire code (HTML + JS)?

Comment: quote from jQuery on documentation: When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector. My words: This means it applies also to elements that got the class later on.

Comment: You can simply do `$("#next-button").removeClass("next-main-button").addClass("next-task-error");` rather than two lines.

Comment: simple delegate to a wrapper: `$(document).on("click", ".next-main-button", nextButtonClick).on("click", ".next-main-button", errorButtonClick);`

Answer (score 2):

The selector that you used to get the element to bind the click handler on (i.e. `.next-task-error` or `.next-main-button`) is only executed once, and delivers one or more elements.

Then you bind a click handler to those element(s), but that binding has no knowledge of the selector you used to get those elements. The binding is done on the elements directly, and never again is their class verified (or whatever other selector you could have used).

To make it more dynamic, you could either (1) use event delegation, or (2) test the clicked element's class at the moment of the event, or (3) change the handler when the condition changes.

#### 1. Event delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", ".next-main-button", function(){
    nextButtonClick();
});

$(document).on("click", ".next-task-error", function(){
    errorButtonClick();
});
```

Shorter version of the same, using chaining:

```
$(document).on("click", ".next-main-button", nextButtonClick)
           .on("click", ".next-task-error", errorButtonClick);
```

#### 2. Test class within the handler:

```
$('#next-button').on("click", function(){
    if($(this).is('.next-main-button')) {
        nextButtonClick();
    } else {
        errorButtonClick();
    }
});
```

#### 3. Alter handler when status changes

This is like you attempted to do: re-bind the correct handler when the condition changes:

```
// set initial click handler
$('#next-button').on("click", function(){
    nextButtonClick();
});

$(".look-task-again").on("click", function(){
    $('#error-popup-message').modal('hide');
    $("#next-button").removeClass("next-main-button");
    $("#next-button").addClass("next-task-error");
    // replace click handler:
    $('#next-button').off("click").on("click", function(){
        errorButtonClick();
    });
});
```

Shorter version, using chaining:

```
// set initial click handler
$('#next-button').on("click", nextButtonClick);

$(".look-task-again").on("click", function(){
    $('#error-popup-message').modal('hide');
    $("#next-button").removeClass("next-main-button")
                     .addClass("next-task-error")
                     .off("click")
                     .on("click", errorButtonClick);
});
```

Comment: I would tend toward the "delegate" on a wrapper option

Comment: Did this answer suit your needs? Could you accept it or leave a comment?